# What are possible reasons that executing cmd.exe from a .NET app can result in a 0xE0434352 exception?

Tags: .net, taskscheduler

I have a .net (C#) console application that runs when I execute via the "start" button in VS2017, and also when I launch the `.exe` file directly. However, when executed via Windows Task Scheduler I get an unspecific error: `0xE0434352`.

I have found that the error is the result of executing this method:

```
internal static class Lib
{
    internal static async Task<String> ExecuteCmd (string txt, string cli = "cmd.exe", string args = "")
    {
        using ( Process cmd = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = cli,
                Arguments = args,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                UseShellExecute = false,
            }
        } )
        {
            cmd.Start();
            await cmd.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync(txt);
            await cmd.StandardInput.FlushAsync();
            cmd.StandardInput.Close();
            cmd.WaitForExit();
            return await cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
}

// Then that method is called from the Main method like so:
public static async Task Main (string[] args)
{
    ExecuteCmd($"echo Complete! >> myFile.log");
}
```

What is the reason for this? The exceptions I get (from the Event Viewer) are:

**Application error**

```
Application: myapp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
   at myapp.App+<Main>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at myapp.App.<Main>(System.String[])
```

**Framework Error**

```
Faulting application name: myapp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5b0d3a3e
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.16299.402, time stamp: 0x81d25214
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00103f12
Faulting process id: 0x51d4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3f752fb93dfdb
Faulting application path: path\to\myapp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: c15aa1dc-fb36-49df-a37c-5866116c39d7
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

============== EDIT ================

During runtime I am retrieving a JSON file from a mapped network drive:

```
IConfiguration jsonConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("X:\configs", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
    .Build();
```

I have found that removing this solves at least one problem. although there may be others

Comment: I'm guessing the user account that the task scheduler is running it under under does not have write permissions to the current working directory. You probably want to make sure the process is running in a specific directory and that the user account used has permissions for that folder.

Comment: @crashmstr - the task is run "with highest privileges". I have also tried executing from a specific location

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant - I don't understand what you mean by the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event? From the linked question that looks like an event handler that would catch such an exception (thanks - I didn't know about that). What do you mean when you say it's not optional?

Comment: Please post the main method. It is throwing the exception.

Comment: Added @ErnodeWeerd

Comment: Mapped drive letters, like X:, are a per-user setting.  Task Scheduler is apt to run the program with a different user account.  And doesn't handle a specific account [all that well either](https://serverfault.com/questions/540427/windows-server-2012-scheduled-tasks-run-using-default-profile-when-ran-session/640875).  Always favor using a UNC path instead, `\\server\share\dir\file.ext` so no config is necessary at all.  Verify that you get a repro for this poor diagnostic by testing with "asdf".

Comment: Is there a question here??

Answer (score -1):

"Windows Task Scheduler"

I bet it'll be the Start In field being empty or malformed. Put the exe's folder in the Start In field, and double quote it.  "C:/YesEven/Paths/Like/This/"

Comment: nope - doesn't help. - quotes give me errors. and specifying the path doesn't change the execution result

Comment: The "Start a program" action editor in the task scheduler specifically indicates that "Start In" is optional, and it does not require quoting under any circumstances.